# Not able to create elasticsearch's mappings for the index created from logstash JDBC input plugin

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Am trying to create `mappings` for elasticsearch `index`. When i create an index with the below query, am able to apply `mappings`.

Please find the query that am create index in elasticsearch

```
put index/profile/1
{
    "firstname" : "Karthik",
    "lastname" : "AS",
    "address" : "4/167, SouthExtn, shanmuga nagar, NA",
    "Skill" : "Java, JEE, ReactJS, ActiveMQ, ElasticSearch",
    "filename" : "My_second_file_created_at_2012.01.13.pdf"
}
```

for the above created index am able to apply `mappings` and able to search successfully. Please find the below `mappings` details

```
    PUT /documents_test8
{
   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "analyzer" : {
            "filename_search" : {
               "tokenizer" : "filename",
               "filter" : ["lowercase"]
            },
            "filename_index" : {
               "tokenizer" : "filename",
               "filter" : ["lowercase","edge_ngram"]
            }
         },
         "tokenizer" : {
            "filename" : {
               "pattern" : "[^\\p{L}\\d]+",
               "type" : "pattern"
            }
         },
         "filter" : {
            "edge_ngram" : {
               "side" : "front",
               "max_gram" : 20,
               "min_gram" : 1,
               "type" : "edgeNGram"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
         "properties" : {
            "filename" : {
               "type" : "text",
               "search_analyzer" : "filename_search",
               "index_analyzer" : "filename_index"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But in actual scenario, am creating index in elasticsearch via logstash JDBC input plugin. Am able to create index in elasticsearch, but the problem once index is created in elasticsearch via logstash by default `mappings` also created for that index (for all the fields). After that am not able to apply my `mappings` it shows `index [documents_test9/P07B6_6mRqmH9IP-UaCjrw] already exists` error. If i try to delete that index and executing this `mapping` am getting `Failed to parse mapping [doc]: No handler for type [string] declared on field [filename]` error.

Not sure, how to apply `mappings` when the index is created via logstash JDBC input plugin

Comment: You're trying to create a 2.x mapping on a 5.x or 6.x ES server. In your mapping, `string` must be replaced with `text`.

Comment: I have updated my actual `mappings` where i changed `String` to `text` and this also giving same error message

Comment: You need to delete the index, recreate it with the proper mapping and repopulate the data

Comment: I have updated my question and showing `filename` in my question. If am trying to search for `file` it should bring the document as result for this, i written `mappings` above

Comment: is that. i have to execute logstash first, then invoke mappings from logstash or how it will be ?

Comment: Your index needs to be clean and properly mapped **before** starting logstash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use a [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) with a wildcard so any new index that contain a name matching in the wildcard will use the given index template by default.

With below template, any index you add which contains the name documents* i.e. `documents1`, `documents_test8` etc, will by default use the given index template.

```
 PUT _template/documents
{
  "template": "documents*",
   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "analyzer" : {
            "filename_search" : {
               "tokenizer" : "filename",
               "filter" : ["lowercase"]
            },
            "filename_index" : {
               "tokenizer" : "filename",
               "filter" : ["lowercase","edge_ngram"]
            }
         },
         "tokenizer" : {
            "filename" : {
               "pattern" : "[^\\p{L}\\d]+",
               "type" : "pattern"
            }
         },
         "filter" : {
            "edge_ngram" : {
               "side" : "front",
               "max_gram" : 20,
               "min_gram" : 1,
               "type" : "edgeNGram"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
         "properties" : {
            "filename" : {
               "type" : "text",
               "search_analyzer" : "filename_search",
               "index_analyzer" : "filename_index"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```